# android duplicate provider authority

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, authority

I have had users complaining of a "duplicate provider authority" error when trying to install my android application. I initially thought it might be an old version interfering with the new version, but they have never installed the app before. Any suggestions as to what might be causing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Somebody else used the same provider authority as you. AFAIK, that's the only way this error can occur. What did you choose as your provider authority?

Comment: thanks, seems i forgot to change the provider authority from what was used in the tutorial. works now